# i cant able to sort (Ascending/Descending) this part of MySql query?

Tags: mysql

**i want to sort these elements either ascending / descending.**

Part of query:

```
sum(CASE WHEN a.question_id=39 AND u.answer_id =215 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as optcount1,
sum(CASE WHEN a.question_id=39 AND u.answer_id =216 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as optcount2,
sum(CASE WHEN a.question_id=39 AND u.answer_id =217 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as optcount3,
sum(CASE WHEN a.question_id=39 AND u.answer_id =218 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as optcount4,
```

Full query:

```
 SELECT 39 AS ques_id,215 as optid1,216 as optid2,217 as optid3,218 as optid4, 
'Easy to start the business' as optans1,
'Lower tax rate than a corporation' as optans2,
'Liability is shared' as optans3,
'Owner has total control and say over business' as optans4, 
sum(CASE WHEN a.question_id=39 AND u.answer_id =215 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as optcount1,
sum(CASE WHEN a.question_id=39 AND u.answer_id =216 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as optcount2,
sum(CASE WHEN a.question_id=39 AND u.answer_id =217 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as optcount3,
sum(CASE WHEN a.question_id=39 AND u.answer_id =218 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as optcount4, 
'217' as answer, 4 as count FROM `user_training_answers_statistics` as u,
answers as a WHERE a.question_id='39' AND u.answer_id=a.answer_id
```

Anyone please give me the solution for this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap it in another query then do the sorting:

```
  select * from
    (SELECT 39 AS ques_id,215 as optid1,216 as optid2,217 as optid3,
            218 as optid4, 'Easy to start the business' as optans1,
            'Lower tax rate than a corporation' as optans2,
            'Liability is shared' as optans3,
            'Owner has total control and say over business' as optans4, 
            sum(CASE WHEN a.question_id=39 AND u.answer_id =215 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
            as optcount1,
            sum(CASE WHEN a.question_id=39 AND u.answer_id =216 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
            as optcount2,
            sum(CASE WHEN a.question_id=39 AND u.answer_id =217 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
           as optcount3,
           sum(CASE WHEN a.question_id=39 AND u.answer_id =218 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
           as optcount4, '217' as answer, 4 as count 
     FROM user_training_answers_statistics as u,
          answers as a
     WHERE a.question_id='39' AND u.answer_id=a.answer_id) as tmpTable
 ORDER BY optcount1, optcount2, optcount3, optcount4 ASC;
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response but here optcount is dynamic value it may be 2 or 4 or 6 something like that. In this case how can i sort this value.

Comment: $sql = "SELECT $qid AS ques_id,$optid $optname $option '$corrctans' as answer, $j as count FROM `user_training_answers_statistics` as u, answers as a WHERE a.question_id='$qid' AND u.answer_id=a.answer_id "; <br> These are dynamic values: $optid $optname $option.